# Identify if html contains template language code while extracting from URL

Tags: php, html-content-extraction

I am trying to fetch plain text content from any provided URL which has some text data. While testing the feature on one of the URLs I found some template language code present in the source.

```
{{if user.username || user.id}}
                {{:user.name}}
```

Any idea how can I clean this code from my output html? Is it possible to achieve something like this using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$filtered_string = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('{{') .
    '.*?' .
    preg_quote('}}') . '/', '', $str);
```

Here `$str` would be your input html